# What happens if i push a nontracking branch?

Tags: git

Consider the following flow:

1) `git checkout -b newbranch`

2) Do some commits....

3)

```
git push
```

Observation

- newbranch is NOT tracking any remote
- on bitbucket, a new branch has been created: 'newbranch'

Why can I push, pull from this branch? I just read http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-5.html, and as far as I understand this shouldn't work.

Because I'm able to use 'newbranch' in collaboration with others , merge etc..

Basically I'm unable to see a difference between a tracking branch and a nontracking branch. This might be because I only use git for special cases where the difference is irrelevant?

Comment: I do understand tracking and how to set it up. The problem is that I don't understand why the nontracking setup works the way it does. I also realized I have been using git like this for a while now

As requested in the comments:

```
$ git config -l
user.email=********$
user.name=*********
push.default=current
color.ui=true
core.editor=vim
credential.helper=cache --timeout=3600
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=********
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

--

Comment: can you provide the output of `git config -l`, running the command in the folder of your project? It may be the branch is actually tracked

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: Which version of git are you using? With 1.7.9.5 I'm unable to push a new local branch to a remote without setting an upstream, so your argumentless `git push` in step 3 fails for me.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the value of `push.default` in your git configuration.

From [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

> current - push the current branch to update a branch with the same name on the receiving end. Works in both central and non-central workflows.

That means `git` simply looks for a branch with a matching name on the server. If you change this value to `upstream` (or `simple` for the matter) you will be unable to push to untracked branches, while `current` and `matching` will let you push also to untracked branches.

Answer (score 1):

Pushing a non tracking branch still pushes that branch. It just doesn't set up tracking. The commits in that branch are pushed to the remote. A branch on the remote is created by the same name, and will contain the same commits, but Git just doesn't track changes on that remote branch to your local branch.

The root reason you can push and pull from this branch has to do with how Git creates commits. Each commit has a parent commit, regardless of whether or not those commits are part of a tracking branch. Basically, commits are a linked list. The pushing and pulling, which really are just merges under the hood, are done based on the commits, not the fact a branch is "tracking" another branch.

Comment: this doesn't really answer his question.. `Why can I push, pull from this branch?`

Comment: I do understand tracking and how to set it up. The problem is that I don't understand why the nontracking setup works the way it does

Comment: @sircapsalot: Updated my answer to better address the question.